# Trouble Parsing JSON Response in Android

Tags: android

i am having a little trouble Parsing a Json response and was hoping i could get some help..

JSon String - null{"ErrorMessage":"","IsSuccess":true,"ReturnValue":2}

Code Example

```
private static String ParseUserResponse(String JsonResponse)
{
    String toReturn =null;

    System.out.println(JsonResponse);
    try
    {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject().getJSONObject(JsonResponse);

        System.out.println(jsonObj.getString("IsSuccess"));
        System.out.println(jsonObj.getString("ReturnValue"));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // TODO: Email Exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return (null);
}
```

i have verifed that the data is getting to this method, but it always blows up and throws the following exception

**09:06.826: INFO/System.out(526): null{"ErrorMessage":"","IsSuccess":true,"ReturnValue":2}
05-20 00:09:06.836: WARN/System.err(526): org.json.JSONException: No value for null{"ErrorMessage":"","IsSuccess":true,"ReturnValue":2}
05-20 00:09:06.856: WARN/System.err(526): at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
05-20 00:09:06.866: WARN/System.err(526): at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:569)
05-20 00:09:06.866: WARN/System.err(526): at com.company.program.class.ParseUserResponse(myclass.java:84)
05-20 00:09:06.876: WARN/System.err(526): at com.company.program.class.isRealUser(myclass.java:57)**

i am working with Android 4.0 SDK if that makes a diffrence.. any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why does your string start with "null" rather than the actual JSON?  That's probably the problem

Comment: Like the nice robot says, the `null` at the start of the input looks like it's not meant to be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be `JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(JsonResponse);` and withuot null at the start of the string

Comment: i had that exact code, and got the exact same issue, i am not sure why the response starts with null, someone else wrote the api i am using and i have no way of removing it.. could i modify the string before sending it to the parser to remove the word null?

Comment: how to you get that JsonResponse?